# replay forms authentication session cookies to ASP.NET via phantomjs

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, session-cookies, phantomjs

### Goal

My goal is to replay a set of ASP.NET Forms Authentication session cookies through a phantomjs script.

### What I've tried

My phantomjs script is below. The script works if I replay the cookies to the website hosted in my local VS2010 ASP.NET Development Server. However, if I try the same code on the website hosted on IIS6, the replay fails.

The replay appears to work fine when the code is running on IIS7

Note: I do realize that the authentication cookies are different for the two different sessions (IIS and ASP.NET Development Server), and I am using the correct cookies for each session.

### Suspicions

I suspect that there is either:

- a problem with the value I am using for the cookie's domain
- a difference between how IIS6 and VS handle authentication cookies, maybe IIS6 won't accept a replay from a different IP?

### Script

```
var page = require('webpage').create();  

var tests = {
    'localhost': {
        url: 'http://localhost/Test.aspx',
        cookies: 
            [{
                "name":"ASP.NET_SessionId"
                ,"value":"abcdefghijk"
                ,"domain":'localhost'
            },{
                "name":".ASPXFORMSAUTH"
                ,"value":"2D23D9EFF2F538..."
                ,"domain":'localhost'
            }]
    },
    'www.myserver.com': {
        url: 'http://www.myserver.com/Test.aspx',
        cookies: 
            [{
                "name":"ASP.NET_SessionId"
                ,"value":"lmnopqrstuv"
                ,"domain":'www.myserver.com'
            },{
                "name":".ASPXFORMSAUTH"
                ,"value":"9EFF2F53823BDA..."
                ,"domain":'www.myserver.com'
            }]      
    }   
};

// uncomment the test you want to perform
var test = tests['localhost'];
// var test = tests['www.myserver.com'];

phantom.addCookie(test.cookies[0]);
phantom.addCookie(test.cookies[1]);

page.open(test.url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {        
        console.log(page.content);
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

#### Work-around:

Since the issue only occurs in my development environment: As a work-around, I created a web service that would return a session and authentication cookie. Then open that service from my PhantomJS script so that the cookie would be added to the current PhantomJS context. Then I would open the real url that I was targeting. Handing our authentication cookies without actually authenticating the user is a bit of a security hole, so I wrap it in compiler directives so that it's not available in the production build.

C#

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, true, "/"));
```

js:

```
page.open(authUrl, function (status) {
    page.open(address, function (status) {
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue. Ever figure this out?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer : I only ever had the issue on IIS6. It worked in IIS7 and ASP.NET Development Server. I just updated my question to add a work-around I used during development (our dev server was IIS6, but prod server was IIS7).

Answer (score 1):

Each machine uses its own specific machine key to encrypt the cookie. Thus, you can't really take a cookie from one machine and use it on another. This would work only if you set the same key on both machines, you can google for more details as this is a common task (having the same key is crucial when you have a web farm).

Also, one of the values encoded in a cookie is its timeout. It means that replays are possible only in a short time window (default is 20 minutes). Cookies issued earlier will just be rejected. This way asp.net defend itself from replay attacks of too old cookies.

Most probably, one of these two issues occur in your scenario.

Edit: after your clarification, another possible reason appears: your phantomjs client lacks headers that would allow asp.net recognize the client supports cookies. A common workaround is to install net 4.5 on the server. An uncommon is to add the parameter to the forms authentication settings:

```
<authentication mode="forms">
   <forms ... cookieless="UseCookies" />
```

which forces the cookie support.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think an expired session is the problem as I am running the tests immediately after creating the session by authentication via the browser. Also, I've edited my script a bit to clarify that I am sending separate cookies to the two different machines. With this edit, do you still think a key mismatch is the issue?

Comment: Is there some way I can see why Forms Authentication is rejecting my cookies? Does it throw any exceptions when it rejects a cookie, or return a status ?

Comment: Nope unfortunately. If it rejects the cookie because it thinks that your browser doesn't support cookies, no error is raised. I lost few hours once to find this one out.